# Select results where equal to multiple numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a user ID and an award ID
User's can obtain different awards or no awards. The query I have set up returns all the users that have either award 1, 2, 3, or 4. I want to return only the users that have all 4 awards.

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT ID
FROM awards
WHERE AID in (1,2,3,4)
```

Again this is returning everyone, and I need it to return just the ID's that have all of them. I am just very unfamiliar with SQL

Comment: Please add sample data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` to group the results by the user's ID and then a `HAVING` clause to count the number of results for each; if any only if the count matches 4 let it be returned:

```
SELECT
    ID
FROM
    awards
WHERE
    AID IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY
    ID
HAVING
    COUNT(ID) = 4
```

If it's possible to award a user with the same award multiple times, you'll want to update the `HAVING` to account for this:

```
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT AID) = 4
```

If not then it should be fine with the first example.

The alternative is to add a long list of `AND AID = x` conditions to your `WHERE` clause (which definitely works and may be easier to remember, but whatever works best for you) =]

Comment: That's actually pretty clever, and it's working. Will accept your answer when available

Comment: This doesn't work correctly unless you have COUNT(DISTINCT AID). If you have 4 rows for a given ID this does not ensure that have each of the 4 values.

Comment: @SeanLange Without knowing the actual table schema, your statement could both be true and false. If a unique key constraint exists between user ID and award ID, no need for `DISTINCT`; without it, sure - it would help. I'll make said comment in the post =]

Comment: It can't be both true and false. ;) True we don't know that if there is a unique constraint on those two columns. In that case I would err on the side of caution and write my code as though there isn't one. Even if there is a unique constraint currently the code should continue to work if that constraint were removed. It is easy to add and isn't going to have much (if any) effect on performance.

Comment: @SeanLange `<joke>`Schrodinger's SQL! Until the schema is observed, it contains and doesn't contain a unique constraint!`</joke>`. Sorry, I had to =P